# How to Logout Windows authentication based lightswitch web application

Tags: windows-authentication, logout, visual-studio-lightswitch

Any idea about implementing **Logout** functionality/button for a Lightswitch web application which is being implemented the **Windows** based authentication.

The authentication type I have used is,

Lightswitch Project properties--> Access Control--> Use Windows Authentication--> Allow any authenticated Windows user.

When I open the same page again, it is not even asking for credentials. It is using the previously logged-in user as an authenticated user.

If I could have used **Forms** authentication, I am able to get the custom Login & Logout forms.

Need help here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "login" action when using Windows authentication, and thus, no "logout" either.  It simply uses the Windows identity of the running app process.  If you launch the process hosting your app under a different identity than what you're logged into Windows with, I suspect that would allow you to use the app as a different user.  You can launch processes as a different user by shift right-clicking the file and selecting "Run as different user".

Comment: Thanks @Matt. It is prompting for a username&password when I browse the web application for the first time. From there on, it is using the same authentication even though I close and reopen the browser. I tried several ways such as... document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache", "false"); but didn't work out. Seeking help to logout by any other manner. Thanks again.